# C++ shared_ptr shared_from_this throws a bad_weak_ptr exception, even though I have a reference to it

Tags: c++, boost-asio, shared-ptr

EDIT: I never figured this out - I refactored the code to be pretty much identical to a Boost sample, and still had the problem.  If anyone else has this problem, yours may be the more common shared_from_this() being called when no shared_ptr exists (or in the constructor).  Otherwise, I recommend just rebuilding from the boost asio samples.

I'm trying to do something that I think is pretty common, but I am having some issues.

I'm using boost asio, and trying to create a TCP server.  I accept connections with async_accept, and I create shared pointers.  I have a long lived object (like a connection manager), that inserts the shared_ptr into a set.  Here is a snippet:

```
std::shared_ptr<WebsocketClient> ptr = std::make_shared<WebsocketClient>(std::move(s));
directory.addPending(ptr);
ptr->onConnect(std::bind(&Directory::addClient, &directory, std::placeholders::_1));
ptr->onDisconnect(std::bind(&Directory::removeClient, &directory, std::placeholders::_1));
ptr->onMessage(std::bind(&Directory::onMessage, &directory, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
ptr->start();
```

The Directory has `std::set<std::shared_ptr<WebsocketClient>> pendingClients;`

The function for adding a client is:

```
void Directory::addPending(std::shared_ptr<WebsocketClient> ptr){
    std::cout << "Added pending client: " << ptr->getName() << std::endl;
    pendingClients.insert(ptr);
}
```

Now, when the WebsocketClient starts, it tries to create a shared_ptr using shared_from_this() and then initiates an async_read_until ("\r\n\r\n"), and passes that shared_ptr to the lambda to keep ownership.  It crashes before actually invoking the asio function, on shared_from_this().

Call stack looks like this:

```
server.exe!WebsocketClient::start()
server.exe!Server::acceptConnection::__l2::<lambda>(boost::system::error_code ec)
server.exe!boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke<boost::asio::detail::binder1<void <lambda>(boost::system::error_code),boost::system::error_code> >(boost::asio::detail::binder1<void <lambda>(boost::system::error_code),boost::system::error_code> & function, ...)
server.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_accept_op<boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >,boost::asio::ip::tcp,void <lambda>(boost::system::error_code) ::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service * owner, boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation * base, const boost::system::error_code & result_ec, unsigned __int64 __formal) Line 142  C++
server.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::do_one(bool ec, boost::system::error_code &)
server.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code & ec)
server.exe!Server::run()
server.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv)
```

However, I get a bad_weak_ptr when I call shared_from_this.  I thought that was thrown when no shared_ptr owned this object, but when I call the addPending, I insert "ptr" into a set, so there should still be a reference to it.

Any ideas?  If you need more details please ask, and I'll provide them.  This is my first post on StackOverflow, so let me know what I can improve.

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697973/shared-from-this-causing-bad-weak-ptr) help you?

Comment: I don't think you can use shared_from_this() in the constructor, which you imply you're doing ("when the WebsocketClient starts...").  It only becomes valid after construction.  Lots of related Q&A around, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598986/weak-pointer-to-this-in-constructor).

Comment: @DafangCao I actually already saw that.  But in my case, I should already have a reference to it, because I insert it into a set (directory.addPending(ptr))

Comment: @TonyD I don't actually call it in the constructor.  The constructor doesn't really do anything other than initialize some values related to the connection.  It's in the start call where I try to do shared_from_this, but at that point there should already be a reference stored (in two places, actually?)

Comment: Nope. Not shared pointers. It's impossible to have them if the object is still being constructed...

Comment: @sehe What?  I don't called shared_from_this while the object is being constructed.  It's already been fully constructed by the time ptr->start is called.  Why did you mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: Oh. Hmm. I misread that then. Reopening. Please make your sample a SSCCE/MCVE

Comment: I can think of a lot of things you might have done wrong, but I can't tell which without enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I can try to add more code.  Could you suggest what might possibly have gone wrong to throw a bad_weak_ptr, if it isn't that I have no references to that object?

Comment: The devil's likely in the details - e.g. "passes that `shared_ptr` to the lambda to keep ownership" - you're not accidentally passing by reference?  Is directory simply a `set<shared_ptr<WebsocketClient>>`?  You may need to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get useful help (actually, it's site policy too)....

Comment: It is that you have no shared_ptr references to that object, but how you got there can be subtle. You could have violated the thread safety requirements for shared pointers. You could think you have a shared_ptr to the object but actually have a shared_ptr to some other object. You might have a reference whose life exceeded the life of the thing it references. You might have mixed std::shared_ptr with boost::shared_ptr.

Comment: Try this: Use a debugger and stop when you get the error. Check the call stack for the invocation of the member function's caller. Make sure that caller called that member function through a shared_ptr. If not, check its caller, and confirm the same. The first member function of the object on which you got the error should have been invoked through a shared_ptr. 100% confirm that it was.

Comment: @TonyD The bad_weak_ptr gets thrown before I actually even give it to the lambda.  It gets thrown inside ptr->start() function.  The directory is a class that has a std::set<std::shared_ptr<WebsocketClient>> pendingClients;  I'll go ahead and edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz By the way, thanks for the help and suggestions.  I really appreciate it.  I did confirm with the debugger that the websocketclient start() function is being called by `ptr->start();`

Comment: @mach990 And `ptr` is a valid `shared_ptr` to the very same object that is calling `shared_from_this`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes.  It's the one that was created with make_shared in the sample above, so the code goes directly into that function, where the very first line is `auto self(shared_from_this());`.  So it's going from creating the shared_ptr to setting up some callbacks, and then invoking the start function, which crashes immediately.  So somehow there's something wrong with the shared_ptr, but I don't know what.

Comment: What happens if you call `ptr->shared_from_this()` immediately after creating it with `make_shared()`? i.e. remove all the other code that adds it to the set and sets callbacks, just test the simplest possible thing that could be going wrong. Does it work then? If that works, try moving the `shared_from_this()` call slightly later. Keep moving it until you find the pointer where it stops working. Call it after adding it to the set. Call it before calling `ptr->start()`. Call it at the very top of the `WebSocketClient::start()` function. Find the first point at which it throws `bad_weak_ptr`.

Comment: And get rid of all the Asio code, it almost certainly isn't relevant or related to your problem. Simplify the `WebsocketClient` class, and move the `shared_ptr` creation code into `main` (instead of having it called inside an Asio call stack). Basically, produce a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as requested several times above. Something like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed3527242f911889 works fine, so figure out which part of your code causes it to behave differently. This is basic debugging: isolate what the problem is, then you can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You could be dealing with memory corruption.  Whether that's the case or not, there are some troubleshooting steps you should definitely take:

1. Log the pointer value returned from `make_shared`, and again inside the member function just before calling `shared_from_this`.  Check whether that pointer value exists in your running object table (which is effectively what that `set<shared_ptr<...>>` is)
2. Instrument constructor and destructor.  If the `shared_ptr` count does actually hit zero, it'll call your destructor and the call stack will give you information on the problem.

If that doesn't help, the fact that you're using `make_shared` should be useful, because it guarantees that the metadata block is right next to the object.

3. Use `memcpy` to dump the raw bytes preceding your object at various times and watch for potential corruption.

Much of this logging will happen in a context that's exhibiting undefined behavior.  If the compiler figures out that you're testing for something that's not supposed to be possible, it might actually remove the test.  In that case, you can usually manage to make the tests work anyway by precision use of `#pragma` to disable optimization just on your debug logging code -- you don't want to change optimization settings on the rest of the code, because that might change the way corruption manifests without actually fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to determine the cause of the problem without a code.
But which `enable_shared_from_this` you use, boost or std?
I see you use `std::make_shared`, so if WebsocketClient inherits `boost::enable_shared_from_this` it can cause crash.